# R - initialize dataframe as quickly as possible

Tags: r

I am trying to increase the speed of code I am working with, step by step, for a project I am currently working on. The project currently requires initializing a dataframe with anywhere between 10M-1B rows and 24 columns to start off the project. The first 8 columns are strings, the next 16 columns are integers, so it has to be a dataframe as opposed to a matrix because of the strings.

Currently I have:

```
starttime = Sys.time()
total_num_lineups = 100000000
lineup = as.data.frame(matrix(nrow = total_num_lineups, ncol = 24))

Sys.time() - starttime
# Time difference of 44.70181 secs
```

which takes about 45 seconds for 100M rows. The project could very well scale over 1B rows, and this is the first bottleneck I am trying to fix. Any thoughts on how to speed up this step would be greatly appreciated.

extra - I can provide additional information on the project if needed, but thought focusing problem by problem may be better. I am open to switching the container (to a datatable, or other structure) if it's faster.

Thanks!

Comment: How did you get this to run?  I got `Error: cannot allocate vector of size 8.9 Gb`

Comment: Rich, I presume that is a memory issue.  Dealing w/ in-memory objects this big can push the limit of what particular systems may handle.  My machine had no trouble with the above code.

Comment: are you positive this step is required?

Comment: You could use two matrices instead. But why do you need to initialize anything?

Answer (score 3):

When it comes to stuff this size, the data.table package is the way to go.

The code below initializes a data.frame as you did, but only with 1 row, converts it to data.table, then repeats the first row to your given dimensions.

```
library(data.table)

starttime = Sys.time()
total_num_lineups = 100000000
lineup = as.data.frame(matrix(nrow = 1, ncol = 24))
dt = as.data.table(lineup)
testit = dt[rep(1,total_num_lineups)]

Sys.time() - starttime
# Time difference of 15.08011 secs
```

Note that the way you are initializing the data.frame makes all the columns doubles, rather than character/integer as you indicated you want.  To get the column types that you want, you can use the following:

```
library(data.table)

starttime = Sys.time()
total_num_lineups = 100000000
lineup = data.frame(
  character(1),
  character(1),
  character(1),
  character(1),
  character(1),
  character(1),
  character(1),
  character(1),
  integer(1),
  integer(1),
  integer(1),
  integer(1),
  integer(1),
  integer(1),
  integer(1),
  integer(1),
  integer(1),
  integer(1),
  integer(1),
  integer(1),
  integer(1),
  integer(1),
  integer(1),
  integer(1)
)
dt = as.data.table(lineup)
lineup = dt[rep(1,total_num_lineups)]

Sys.time() - starttime
# Time difference of 15.08011 secs
```

Comment: Why convert to a `data.frame` and then to a `data.table`? You can create the data directly with `data.table` or `as.data.table` or even convert the `data.frame` to a `data.table` *in place* by doing `setDT(lineup)`. Also, I don't see a comparison of `data.table` to a `data.frame` performance here. Also, maybe doing `dt[rep(1,total_num_lineups), ]` within a `matrix` would be faster than both. All in all, just saying "*data.table is the way to go!*" is not hard enough evidence IMO.